# Typedef of private class without exposing it

Tags: c++

When using multiple nested classes it becomes unnecessarily verbose to spell out the full class name, typedef can help with public classes but when using on private, typedef can not access the class. Is there a way to use typedef or something similar without making the class visible?

EDIT:

example:

classA.h

```
class Class_A {
    private:
      class Class_B;
  };
```

classB.h

```
class ClassA::Class_B {
    private:
      class Class_C;
      void func();
  };
```

classB.cpp

```
 void Class_A::Class_B::func(){
       // Do something
    };
```

Cannot do the following to make the name shorter:

```
typedef Class_A::Class_B td_classB;
```

Comment: Why would you want the `typedef` visible but the class not visisble?

Comment: Can you give an example? It is not really clear what is the problem. Just give the typedef same visibility as the class

Comment: when I declare the class in a header file and want to define a function from that class in cpp  file I have to write the full class name to access that function.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It will be so much simpler to suggest a solution with actual code.

Comment: So in other words, you are looking for a way to not have to write full method signature in source file?

Comment: The code shown is completely bogus.

Comment: You may want to refactor classes from nested to free standing.  This would reduce the length of the scope.

Comment: @ Tomasz Plaskota  Yes I want the full method signature shorter.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It's not "completely bogus" at all. The only question is whether nested classes (particularly with multiple levels in the tree) are a good idea. Okay, to be fair, the OP wrote `Class` instead of `class` in a couple of places.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot do the following to make the name shorter:
>
> ```
> typedef Class_A::Class_B td_classB;
> ```

It makes sense that you can't do that any old place. After all, `Class_B` is a `private` nested class of `Class_A`.

You can use that in any class or function that has access to the `private` section of the class.